# How can I log Sofia SIP requests/responses

Tags: sip, restcomm

I'm working on a telephony application and use Sofia SIP as signalling stack. I'm trying to find a way to log SIP requests/responses to be able to troubleshoot signalling issues. The problem is that I can't seem to find a way to retrieve a 'serialized' form of the SIP header from Sofia's data structures.

I have tried:

- Checking existing Sofia logging facilities to see if they log something similar but after enabling all facilities (i.e. nua, nta, nea, etc), I see no such info.
- Retrieving the data from the sip_t structure nua is passing my application but haven't found a way to serialize that data (I did find a sip_e routine which is supposed to encode a sip_t data structure, but it seems that only a declaration is included in the Sofia sources -no implementation)

I know that I can probably find a way to hack Sofia code to do that but I'd rather not

Any ideas are welcome

Thanks a lot,
Antonis

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix that (forgot to post my solution back here, apologies). So the way to do it was to set the TPORT_LOG env variable accordingly when initializing Sofia (in my case before calling nua_create):

```
setenv("TPORT_LOG", "1", 1);
```

Hope this helps,
Antonis Tsakiridis